# Is the time complexity of this algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've solved the bellow algorithm and found the time complexity to be

O(nlgn*log(base3)n)

```
for (a=1;a<=n;a++)

   for (b=1;b<=n/2;b++)

     for (c=1;c<=n;c*=3)

        print("A")
```

Now I have this other algorithm:

```
for (a=1;a<=n;a++) 

      for (b=1;b<=a^2;b++)

          for (c=1;c<=n/2;c++)

            print("A2")
```

Will the time complexity be O(n^4 lgn)? if not please explain why.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are mistaken having said that time complexity of the first algo is O(n * lgn * log<sub>3</sub>n). It is O(n<sup>2</sup> * log<sub>3</sub>n). A loop for `b` runs in O(n) not in O(lgn).

In the second algo lets take a look at `c` loop, it is T<sub>c</sub> = O(n). If we omit `c` loop we will actually reduce time in O(n) so `c` loop brings a multiplier of `n` to time complexity formula.

Let's have a look at `a` and `b`. `b` depends on the values of `a`. The number of times the body of `b` loop will be executed is

T<sub>a,b</sub> = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + ... + n<sup>2</sup>

It is a well knows formula of the sum of squares of natural numbers.

∑n<sup>2</sup> = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Eventually we have

T<sub>a,b,c</sub> = T<sub>a,b</sub> * T<sub>c</sub> = O(n<sup>3</sup>) * O(n) = O(n<sup>4</sup>)

I see you for some reason associate `n/2` with O(lgn). The loop `for(i=1;i<=n/2;i++)` runs twice less times than `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`, doesn't it? They both have complexity O(n). It has nothing to do with lgn.

Comment: aha I get it now! Thank you very much